# How to build a URL / Query in Golang

Tags: go

**Background -**

I need to build a URL / query based on user input from a form that will be used to make an API call.

**Problem -**

When building the URL, the params are not properly escaped. For example, the query "bad santa" ends up with a space between it instead of "+".

Current Output -

> e.g. https://api.example.org/3/search/movie?query=bad
> santa&api_key=#######

Expected Output -

> e.g. https://api.example.org/3/search/movie?query=bad+santa&api_key=#######

**Code Example -**

Root URL -

```
var SearchUrl = "https://www.example.org/3/search/movie?query="
```

Get params taken from user input -

```
var MovieSearch []string = r.Form["GetSearchKey"]
```

API Key -

```
var apiKey = "&api_key=######"
```

I am using the `ArrayToString()` to parse the form input data

```
func ArrayToString(array []string) string{
    str := strings.Join(array, "+")
    return str 
}
```

Then building the URL -

```
var SearchUrl = "https://api.example.org/3/search/movie?query="
var MovieSearch []string = r.Form["GetSearchKey"]  
var apiKey = "&api_key=########"
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, ArrayToString(MovieSearch), apiKey}
OUTPUT_STRING := ArrayToString(UrlBuild)
```

**Question -**

How to build a URL with user input GET params that are escaped properly?

Comment: I think your input slice is probably wrong, and that is why the join isn't producing what you're expecting.

Comment: the errors about url.QueryEscape are likely that you have a global var somewhere named "url" (or a var in this function but not in what you pasted to us).  basically, you've shadowed the package url with a string named url. rename the variable url and it should work fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, one should use url package's Values.

Here's an example, that does what I think you want, [on play](http://play.golang.org/p/9gC6NNW--_)
Both a simple main, and in http.HandlerFunc form:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/url"
import "net/http"

func main() {
    baseURL := "https://www.example.org/3/search/movie"
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("query", "this is a value")
    perform := baseURL + "?" + v.Encode()
    fmt.Println("Perform:", perform)
}

func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    baseURL := "https://www.example.org/3/search/movie"
    v := url.Values{}

    v.Set("query", r.Form.Get("GetSearchKey")) // take GetSearchKey from submitted form
    v.Set("api_ley", "YOURKEY") // whatever your api key is

    perform := baseURL + "?" + v.Encode() // put it all together
    fmt.Println("Perform:", perform) // do something with it
}
```

Output:
`Perform: https://www.example.org/3/search/movie?query=this+is+a+value`

Notice how the values are put in to query string, properly escaped, for you.

Comment: r.Form is the same type (url.Values)... Just use r.Form.Get("key") and you get a single string.  The only reason the underlying map uses a map[string][]string is because it's legal for a form to submit the same form key twice.  if your html doesn't do that, just use the first field just like Values.Get does ( https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=19773:19811#L698 )

Comment: correct, and I updated my example.   Warning, I didn't run the handler itself, but it compiles.  and that code is simple enough that compiles probably == works

Comment: I'd guess the down votes were for a couple reasons.  The title doesn't really match the problem (generating urls).  Your solution is fairly complex and not in a copy&paste form, so hard to drop in an editor to see what is wrong.   Also, only errors in the question are related to code not in the example.  People are more likely to help if you boil problem down in to an easy to reproduce, runnable thing.  Having a link to the problematic code on play.golang.org is also super helpful.  Make sure the question always has the code as well, no everyone will click the link to Play.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks a lot man. I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape parameters using https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape, instead of doing it yourself.

Besides you should be using https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL to build up your url:

```
params := fmt.Sprintf("?query=%s&api_key=######", url.QueryEscape("name"))
perform := url.URL{
    Scheme:     "https",  
    Host:       "api.example.com",
    Path:       "3/search/movie",
    RawQuery:   params,
}

fmt.Println(perform) // <- Calls .String()
```

I recommend to check https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html.

If your data comes in []string:

```
func ArrayToQuery(values []string) string {
    return url.QueryEscape(strings.Join(values, " "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MovieSearch` contains one element with the value "bad santa", what you're seeing looks correct. It's joining those three strings and putting "+" between them.

Comment: But should that end up like this,  
     
But it needs to be example.com/value?bad+santa

Answer (score -1):

If there is a space in the word you will need to replace it.

Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace("bad santa", " ", "+", -1))
}
```

So you should probably do it like this

```
func main() {
    a := []string{"bad", "santa"}
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", a)
    j := ArrayToString(a)
    strings.Replace(j, " ", "+",-1)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", j)
}
```

Here is a link to the Go Documentation - https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace